# Print only the name of first author without the 'et al.' when citing?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

If one wants to replace 'et al' with something else, eg, "and co-workers" for some instances only, a citation mode that only produced the name would make that possible. Unfortunately, the `\citeauthor{}` in natbib adds the 'et al.' and there is no `\citefirstauthor` or something else that would create this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You may want to try this command to define what you want to appear `\defcitealias{ref_in_natbib}{alias_you_want_to_see_in_your_document}`, and then you call it with the command `\citetalias{ref_in_natbib}`. The problem with this solution is that you'll have to redefine all your references (or at least all the ones you want to modify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you specify in your question "for some instances only", a non-automated solution would be to define an alias for the entries of your bibliography you want to modify. This can be done by the command

```
\defcitealias{key_in_your_bibliography}{alias_you_want_to_see}
```

Then to get the desired output when citing the references you have to use the command

```
\citetalias{key_in_your_bibliography}
```

or the command

```
\citepalias{key_in_your_bibliography}
```

if you want to have parenthesis around the alias.

The definition of the alias has to be done after the `\begin{document}` and before the first use of the `\citetalias` and `\citepalias` for the corresponding entry.